# Python Dataframe - Keep data as string while loading from_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import-from-csv

from_csv picks up a '04' as one of the values and converts it to a string. How do I make sure that all columns being picked up are as string? I would want to avoid handling individual columns as there are 114 columns and I do not want to go thru the exercise of analyzing while columns are impacted.

Comment: CORRETION: and converts it to an INT

Comment: Not really a duplicate. load from csv is not a problem. Problem is when you use from_csv method is DataFrame

Comment: @PankajSingh you can [edit] your question to include corrections...

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv `dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} (Unsupported with engine=’python’). Use str or object to preserve and not interpret dtype.` -- > dtype=str

Comment: You can just do `df = pd.read_csv(your_filepath, dtype=str)`

Answer (score 6):

If you want all columns to be `str` then pass `dtype=str` to `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, dtype=str)
```

will preserve any leading zeroes

Example:

```
In [54]:
t="""a,b
001,230
01,003"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), dtype=str)
df

Out[54]:
     a    b
0  001  230
1   01  003
```

here the dtypes will be listed as `object` which is the correct dtype for `str` here:

```
In [55]:
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    2 non-null object
b    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 112.0+ bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you have only a limited number of columns to read as strings**:

Instead of from_csv use `read_csv` ([here the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)) and set

```
dtype={ 'your_column_name':np.str_ }
```

**If all the data should be considered a string**:

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, the suggested solution removes trailing zeroes from the data. [EdChum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42652990/3214872) handles this case as requested.

<s>Just convert the data after reading it with `df.asType(np.str_)`. You can also convert a set of columns (of which you will still need the names though) by putting all the names in a list and then doing `df[list_of_column_names] = df[list_of_column_names].asType(np.str_)`</s>

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to avoid. I have 114 columns. Above suggestion would make it set datatype for 114 columns

Comment: See the updated answer for more options to avoid specifying all column names

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but If converted after reading then '04' that was converted to 4 will become '4', which means information may be lost.

Comment: In that case trailing zeroes are removed, yes.